# SQL Server aggregate function with sum

Tags: sql-server, function, aggregate

I want to use an aggregate function in SQL Server to sum the number of seats:

The table is like that (it's all the same software just version changes)

```
 OrderID |  CustomerID | ProductID  | Product Name       |    No of Seats

    1       |  11         | 351-0212-4 | soft v601,Download  |  3
    2       |  11         | 361-0313-5 | soft v701,Upgrade   |  2
    3       |  12         | 341-1210-4 | soft v501,Download  |  5
    4       |  12         | 351-0212-5 | soft v601,Upgrade   |  2
    ...
```

And I want a result like

```
 Sum(no of seats) 
   8
```

So If a customer already bought the software but have upgraded keep number of seats for the customer.

e.g.:

Customer 11 bought 3 licences of our soft and then he bought two upgrades of a newer vesion so the sum for him should be 3 instead of 5.

Is that something possible to do in SQL ?
I hope I've been clear if not let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a download is a purchase of seats, but an upgrade isn't? What if the same customer has more than one download? Are there other types of product, apart from download and upgrade? Can a customer ever purchase more seats with an upgrade? Do you have a Product table with these details on?

Comment: So what is the issue? Just filter out the upgrades before aggregating the results. It would be easier to sum only downloads if the words `Download` and `Upgrade` were stored in a separate column rather than attached to a product name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
select CustomerID, sum([No of Seats])
from <your table>
where [Product Name] not like '%upgrade%'
group by CustomerID
```

But in general - filter out those you don't want to see in the results and then sum. And if you want total number (not per customer):

```
select sum([No of Seats])
from <your table>
where [Product Name] not like '%upgrade%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add boolean column, like 'isActive', then your select can be like this

```
select customerid, sum(numberOfSeats) from table
where isActive = 1 
group by customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some normalization problems.  The `Product Name` column is (presumably) redundant with the `ProductID` column, *plus* `Product Name`
apparently carries two logically distinct pieces of information: the name itself, and whether that product is an upgrade.

It would be better to split this into two tables, say `Products` and `Orders`.  The `Products` table would have columns `ProductID` (primary key), `Product_Name`, and `Is_Upgrade`, and the `Orders` table would have columns `OrderID` (primary key), `CustomerID` (foreign key), `ProductID` (foreign key), and `NumberOfSeats`.

Given what you now have, however, and assuming that you want to avoid counting seats where the product name ends in 'Upgrade', you seem to want a query along these lines:

```
SELECT SUM("No of seats")
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 11 AND "Product Name" NOT LIKE '%Upgrade'
```